# "Forgiving" expressions in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In one React JSX view, I have an expression `{a.b.c}` that crashes the whole view because sometimes `b` is `undefined`. Is there a module providing [the same behaviour than expressions in AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#forgiving)? I prefer an expression displaying nothing instead of crashing the view. Should I write something like `{((a||{}).b||{}).c}` for example?

Comment: *"Is there a module providing...."* It's just JavaScript. You can use any existing solution/module that solves this problem. If you wonder whether *React* provides such a functionality: no. Why should it?

Comment: React is just pure javascript and its expression are not different than those in pure javascript while same is not the case in angular. So you won't be able to use `{a.b.c}` as a forgiving expression in React

Comment: @FelixKling His question is valid; no need for arrogance. Angular handles these situations elegantly, no stack is generated for undefined, so it's not "just JavaScript" in his world. Considering he's unfamiliar with React, his question is more than reasonable.

Comment: Ok. I guess I can use Lodash's _.get or similar, but I am looking for something more integrated with React.

I am not a React power-user so I cannot say whether React should have this functionality. It just seems missing coming from AngularJS.

Comment: @lux: didn't mean to sound arrogant. Just think it's important to understand that React is primarily just JS. Angular has its own template language thingy.

Comment: @lux Felix didn't sound arrogant to me... fwiw Angular's handling of expressions is pretty much *the* thing I hate most about it, and the reason I abandoned it, so it seems there are various opinions on this. In the end React "expressions are just JavaScript" is right, and any new React dev should have those words ringing in their mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Felix Kling answered this in the comments: **React expressions are just JavaScript.** You can use any JavaScript technique to avoid undefined TypeErrors, or any library that helps you out.

Using vanilla JavaScript you can use:

```
<Component prop={a && a.b && a.b.c} />
```

Answer (score 0):

With a deeply nested structures it might be handy to use [`dot-prop`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/dot-prop).

```
dotProp.get(a, 'b.c');
```